# HTML SELECT OPTION convert/changed to <UL> <LI>

Tags: html, list, magento, html-select

I want my code below to be converted or changed to list style or div.

```
        <div class="input-box">
            <select id="<?php echo $_code ?>_cc_type" name="payment[cc_type]" class="required-entry validate-cc-type-select">
                <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('--Please Select--')?></option>
                <?php $_ccType = $this->getInfoData('cc_type') ?>
                <?php foreach ($this->getCcAvailableTypes() as $_typeCode => $_typeName): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $_typeCode ?>"<?php if($_typeCode==$_ccType): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif ?>><?php echo $_typeName ?></option>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </select>
         </div>
```

Instead of having this on dropdown selection, i just want it display as list selection with validation properly working.

Thanks!

Comment: thanks man, unfortunately it doesn't work. i tried changing SELECT -> UL and OPTION -> LI but my validation doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have tried to work on the same concept.
May this would help.

*FYI, this is not full-fledged code. I am still working on it.*

**SCRIPT**

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.customSelect = function( options ) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            //mainWidth: '200', 
            selected: '0',
            alignRight: 'false',
        }, options );

        return this.each(function() {
            var el          = $(this);
            var name        = el.prop('name');

            var optionTag   = el.children();
            var wrapperDIV  = $('<div class="customSelect"/>');
            var newDIV      = $('<div class="custom-select"/>');
            var inputTag    = $("<input name='"+name+"' type='text' readonly='readonly' />").hide();
            var inputDummy  = $("<div class='input-dummy'/>");
            var valueHolder = $('<div class="value-holder clearfix"/>');
            var ULTag       = $('<ul class="clearfix"/>');
            var spanTag     = '<span/>'




            el.wrap(wrapperDIV);
            el.parent().append(newDIV);

            newDIV.append(valueHolder);
            valueHolder.append(spanTag);
            valueHolder.append(inputTag);
            valueHolder.append(inputDummy);
            newDIV.append(ULTag);


            optionTag.each(function(){
                ULTag.append("<li data-selected='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</li>");
            }).end().remove();

            var valDefault  = $('li').eq(settings.selected - 1).val();
            var textDefault = $('li').eq(settings.selected - 1).text();
            $(inputTag).val(valDefault);
            $(inputDummy).text(textDefault);

            valueHolder.click(function(){
                $(this).next().toggle();
            });

            ULTag.each(function(){
                $('li',this ).click(function(){
                    $(this).each(function(){
                        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                        var x = $(this).data('selected');
                        var y = $(this).text();
                        $(inputTag).val(x);
                        $(inputDummy).text(y);
                        $(this).parent().hide();
                    });
                });
            });

            if(settings.selectorRight == 'true'){
                inputDummy.css('float', 'right');
                //valueHolder.css('float', 'right');
            }
            else{
                inputDummy.css('float', 'left');
                //valueHolder.css('float', 'left');
            }

            var woVH = valueHolder.width();
            inputDummy.width(woVH-20);
            ULTag.width(woVH);


        });
    };

}( jQuery ));
```

Related to: [Custom SelectBox (UL-LI) with same functionality in HTML FORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183800/custom-selectbox-ul-li-with-same-functionality-in-html-form)
[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kutec/358p1816/)